# how to change the body background color when select list option for that color is selected using css

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE4Fw.png)
Something is wrong.

Comment: Please post your code here

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter to pass selected value and then just change color with function...

```js
function change(x){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = x;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="blue">
<select id="select" onchange='change(document.getElementById("select").value)'>
  <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
</select>
</body>
```